# Download files of specific a MIME type using Google Drive Android API

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I am new to Android programming. I am writing an application to download files of a specific MIME type from the Google Drive using the Google Drive Android API. Is this possible?
I'm looking for code snippets or links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a read through the [Android API's documentation on queries](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/queries).

```
Query query = new Query.Builder().addFilter(
    Filters.eq(SearchableField.MIME_TYPE, "text/plain"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for answering the question @Dan, but i solved this a week ago using  a little bit different approach from yours

```
Files.List request = mService.files().list()
                                .setQ("mimeType contains 'application/' ");

                        FileList files = request.execute();
```

in the place of application we can put imagess ,videos etc or any mime type application/ downloads all the application files if you want more specific type of file then use `'application/vnd.android.package-archive'` for apk files etc.